# How to get value of data send by post method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a .aspx page which contains form. I am setting another page at the action event of the form. Now I want to send data from one aspx form to another aspx form via post method. How can I access those data on second form??? I am sending data through JQuery.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    //debugger;
    // $(document).ready(function() {
    //   alert('hello there');
    //});
    function test() {

        $("#test").load("test.aspx").toggle();
        // alert($("#frm").serialize());
        // var txt = '<%= Hidden1 %>';
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%= Hidden1.ClientID %>').value;
        alert(txt);
        //  return false;
        $.post("test.aspx", document.getElementById("<%= frm.ClientID %>").serialize,  function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
            /*$.post("test.aspx",
            {
                name: txt
            },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });*/
        return false;
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :  `Request.Form["username"]`

where "username" are the Names of the controls on the posting page.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, you can set a button's post back url property to the url of the second page, and in the second page you can get all the elements of the first page from the Page.PerviosPage object
Example

```
TextBox txt = 
                (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("serverNameText");
```